# Login with url paramaters

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a login system of sorts that uses parameters from the URL.
The parameters are set no problem. I dont know what the issue is.
Here's my code:

```
<?php
require_once("db_const.php");
$mysqli = new mysqli("dont", "try", "to login to", "my database");
# check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
    exit();
}

$username = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"username",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$password = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"password",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE username LIKE '{$username}' AND password LIKE '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
        echo "failed";
    } else {
        echo "success";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ohhhh boy. Please use an existing authentication system or follow a vetted tutorial.

Comment: Really? Credentials as url parameters? I suggest you use a token instead of the login parameters or use `$_POST` on submitting forms.

Comment: try `$sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE username=$username AND password=$password";`

Comment: Sorry, @deadlock, that is not advisable. "WHERE a = b" implied b is a column (or other database object). " WHERE a = 'b; " implies b is a string value.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

`$sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";`

---

### CAUTION

Even if the above code solves your problem, It's still very dangerous as it's vulnerable for **SQL injection** on both *username* and *password* parameters and it can be exploited in a manner that a malicious user can bypass the login check by breaking out of the quotes and adding a condition that evaluates to `true`.

You can use a [`mysqli::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to get over that.

```
$stmt = mysqli->prepare("SELECT * from users WHERE username=? AND password=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username,$password);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: @crafter I just missed the quotes :)

Answer (score -1):

There are a few problems with your code.

The problem is the use of the LIKE function. Your usage is

```
SELECT * from users WHERE username LIKE '{$username}' AND password LIKE '{$password}' LIMIT 1
```

Like requires additional specification to find match positions and such, for example :

```
SELECT ... WHERE username LIKE '%{$username}%'
```

In the form you used, the WHERE clause if equivalent to

```
SELECT ... WHERE username = '{$username}'
```

In addition, LIKE is not recommended even (especially) with the wildcards, as 'tom' will match users 'tom' and 'tommy', and the count will certainly not be == 1.

I'll also urge you to test the query for errors

```
if (!$result) {
   echo 'An error occurred : $mysqli->error;
}
```

Others have already mentioned the risk in passwing username and passwords on the URL, Please take note of their comments.

In addition, storing the password in plain form the database is not recommended for security reasons. There are plenty of resources explaining how to encrypt passwords and authenticate using the encrypted values.

Comment: `$password=' or 1=1;`

Comment: Using `LIKE` for username and password is a VERY bad thing to do. Your queries are vulnerable. Please stop teaching OP's how to solve a small problem to fall into a big one. downvote!

Comment: @ deadlock. I accept your downvote. However, I was expanding on the code provided by the OP where the LIKE command was used, I was not promoting it. I even said "In addition, LIKE is not recommended...". Maybe you missed that part.